# Exercise 3-2 in K&R escape.. program works but have a minor issue

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, escaping

Exercise 3-2. Write a function escape(s,t) that converts characters like newline and tab into visible escape sequences like \n and \t as it copies the string t to s. Use a switch. Write a function for the other direction as well, converting escape sequences into the real characters.

Hey guys, my program works fine, but do you guys know why the program still works when I take out s[s_index] = 0? Shouldn't there be a memory error causing it to print out garbage after the actual string?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void escape(char s[], char t[]);

int main() {
    char s[50];
    char t[50] = "hello\nguys\tbye \t \n h  k   eew l   ";
    escape(s, t);
    printf("%s\n", t);
    printf("%s\n", s);
}  

void escape(char s[], char t[]) {
    int s_index = 0;
    int t_index = 0;
    while (t[t_index] != '\0') {
        switch (t[t_index]) {
            case ('\n'):
                s[s_index] = '\\';
                s[s_index + 1] = 'n';
                t_index++;
                s_index = s_index + 2;
                break;
            case ('\t'):
                s[s_index] = '\\';
                s[s_index + 1] = 't';
                t_index++;
                s_index = s_index + 2;
                break;
            default:
                s[s_index] = t[t_index];
                s_index++;
                t_index++;
                break;
        }
    }
    //s[s_index] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: " Shouldn't there be a memory error causing it to print out garbage after the actual string?" No - that would be defined behavior.  When code does not properly terminate a `char` array to form a string and printing it is attempted, anything can happen - that is undefined behavior.

Comment: it work fine if `char s[50]` is initialized with all zeros . 
However, there is a need to put `0` at the end explicitly that you can not expect it.

Answer (score 0):

When you define an array using

```
char s[50];
```

it's up to the compiler how to initialize `s`. The standard does not mandate how they should be initialized. The safest bet is to assume that they are initialized to garbage. Under that assumption, it's best to have the line:

```
s[s_index] = '\0';
```

Looks like your compiler is initializing `s` with `0`s, and you are seeing reasonable behavior.

You can intialize `s` with `0`s using

```
char s[50] = {0};
```

Even if you did that, it's better to have the line

```
s[s_index] = '\0';
```

in `escape`. It's safer to assume in `escape` that `s` has been initialized with garbage values.